# Retrieving latest file in a directory from a remote server

Tags: bash, http

I was hoping to crack this myself, but it seems I have fallen at the first hurdle because I can't make head nor tale of other options I've read about.

I wish to access a database file hosted as follows (i.e. the `hhsuite_dbs` is a folder containing several databases)

```
http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~compbiol/data/hhsuite/databases/hhsuite_dbs/pdb70_08Oct15.tgz
```

Periodically, they update these databases, and so I want to download the lastest version. My plan is to run a bash script via `cron`, most likely monthly (though I've yet to even tackle the scheduling aspect of the task).

I believe the database is refreshed fortnightly, so if my script runs monthly I can expect there to be a new version. I'll then be running downstream programs that require the database.

My question is then, how do I go about retrieving this (and for a little more finesse I'd perhaps like to be able to check whether the remote file has changed in name or content to avoid a large download if unnecessary)? Is the best approach to query the name of the file, or the file property of date last modified (given that they may change the naming syntax of the file too?). To my naive brain, some kind of globbing of the `pdb70` (something I think I can rely on to be in the filename) then pulled down with `wget` was all I had come up with so far.

***EDIT*** Another confounding issue that has just occurred to me is that the file I want wont necessarily be *the* newest in the folder (as there are other types of databases there too), but rather, I need the newest version of, in this case, the `pdb70` database.

Solutions I've looked at so far have mentioned `weex`, `lftp`, `curlftpls` but all of these seem to suggest logins/passwords for the server which I don't have/need if I was to just download it via the web. I've also seen mention of `rsync`, but of a cursory read it seems like people are steering clear of it for FTP uses.

Comment: I assume the filename changes, as it appears to have a date in it. Firstly, do you know for sure what formula/schedule they're using to generate new files, or do you have some other source, like a parseable web page, which can tell you the name of the latest file?  Secondly, there should be no problem using standard tools like curl or wget or fetch, but it would help to know what operating system you're on, as the tools vary by platform.

Comment: I should say that if you're fetching things via HTTP (as the URL suggests) rather than FTP (as your tags suggest), then you don't have a reliable way to query the directory in which the file is contained. If you're pretty sure that the web server will leave "Indexes" turned on, so that you can parse http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~compbiol/data/hhsuite/databases/hhsuite_dbs/, we can perhaps answer with that assumption in mind. It would be great to see your own attempt though, even if it's just a start, or meta-code.

Comment: Yes I had figured the filename would likely change (and looking at the webpage corresponding to that URL as well as the manual, they dont seem to stick to any one format). I'm afraid I know nothing about how they generate the file at the moment. The link above is the only one I have, and is of the format they suggest in the manual. FYI I will be doing all this from a Linux server (Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin), and bash scripting is the most familiar to me (though thats not saying a lot) so that's how I had intended to proceed (not least because I'll be calling other progs later on).

Comment: Oh yes my mistake, I'd gotten muddled up as they called it an FTP on one of their pages, but the download link is indeed HTTP, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few barriers in your way for this.

My first suggestion is that rather than getting the filename itself, you simply mirror the directory using `wget`, which should already be installed on your Ubuntu system, and let `wget` figure out what to download.

```
base="http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~compbiol/data/hhsuite/databases/hhsuite_dbs/"

cd /some/place/safe/
wget --mirror -nd "$base"
```

And new files will be created in the "safe" directory.

But that just gets you your mirror.  You're still after is the "newest" file.

Luckily, wget sets the datestamp of files it downloads, if it can. So after mirroring, you might be able to do something like:

```
newestfile=$(ls -t /some/place/safe/pdb70*gz | head -1)
```

Note that this fails if ever there are newlines in the filename.

Another possibility might be to check the difference between the current file list and the last one.  Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

base="http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~compbiol/data/hhsuite/databases/hhsuite_dbs/"

cd /some/place/safe/
wget --mirror -nd "$base"
rm index.html* *.gif       # remove debris from mirroring an index

ls > /tmp/filelist.txt.$$
if [ -f /tmp/filelist.txt ]; then
  echo "Difference since last check:"
  diff /tmp/filelist.txt /tmp/filelist.txt.$$
fi
mv /tmp/filelist.txt.$$ /tmp/filelist.txt
```

You can parse the diff output (`man diff` for more options) to determine what file has been added.

Of course, with a solution like this, you could run your script every day and hopefully download a new update within a day of it being ready, rather than a fortnight later.  Nice thing about `--mirror` is that it won't download files that are already on-hand.

Oh, and I haven't tested what I've written here.  That's one monstrously large file.

Comment: Thanks ghoti, yet again you've saved me! I've been chatting to one of the programmers at work and it seems like `wget` is the way forward. It has far more functionality than I realised and I like the idea of mirroring the directory. I'll cobble together an attempt at a script and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Happy to help! Yes, this is true of more than just wget; it's amazing what one can do with many of the tools in our systems. Good luck in your scripting! If my answer helped, please feel free to bestow a fancy green checkmark.

Comment: Can you help me finesse this a little? So far the only command I've been able to get to successfully pull down the pdb database is this one: `wget -r -l1 -np "$base" -nH --cut-dirs=1 -P . -A "*.tgz"`  however this gives me all the directories, .txt files and other databases with the .tgz extension. I've tried some of the variations of `--cut-dirs=` and the -nd flag, but I subsequently break it and it will then only end up giving me the index.html.